# With Active Record, how can I get a random unviewed article?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails app that has a couple models: Article, and UserArticleViews.

Articles have article ids.

UserArticleViews have user ids and article ids, and correspond to a user having viewed an article.

This uses belongs_to and has_many.

Is there an efficient way to get a new article that the user hasn't seen. Something like: select an article, at random, such that there is no UserArticleView with that user_id and article_id?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to get random article using ruby `Array#sample` method (to get random at the application, not database, level as random() is kinda slow at database level):

```
viewed_article_ids = UserArticleView.where(user_id: user_in_question.id).pluck(:article_id)
random_article_id = (Article.pluck(:id) - viewed_article_ids).sample
Article.find(random_article_id)
```

Comment: That might work with a small number, but it seems inefficient because you have to have a large number of ids in memory. Still, thanks...

Comment: How many articles and views you expect to have? Will it be in the range of millions or more? (I'm interested in what is your take on "small" versus "big").

Answer (score 0):

You can View the random record like this also

```
     offset = rand(Article.count)
     rand_record = Article.offset(offset).first
```

Comment: That produces a random record, but it doesn't guarantee that it's an Article the user doesn't already belong to, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Try following for single query

```
article = Article.join("LEFT JOIN user_article_views uav ON uav.article_id = articles.id AND uav.user_id = #{user_id}")
                 .where("uav.id IS NULL")
                 .order("random()")
                 .limit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have the associations:

```
class User
  has_many :article_views
  has_many :articles, :through => :article views
end

class Article
  has_many :article_views
  has_many :users, :through => :article views
end

class ArticleViews
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article
end
```

If this is true, then I think this will work (a `@user` instance method):

```
def random_unread
  unviewed = false
  until unviewed
    @article = Article.offset(rand(Article.count)).first
    unviewed = true unless articles.include?(@article)
  end
  @article
end
```

This assumes that the above is faster than:

```
Article.all.select{|a| !articles.include?(a)}.sample
```